# In JTable ,I create custom table model by extendind AbstractTableModel and use it , only the default column name(A,B,C,D,..) appear

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i am using this class , the table heading appears as A B C D .

class CustomTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{

```
 String[] columnNames = {"FirstName","LastName","Contact","eMail"};<br/>
//private Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
 private Vector<String[]> data = new Vector<String[]>();

 CustomTableModel()
  {
        String[] a = {"a","s","d","f"};
        this.data.addElement(a);
  }

public int getColumnCount() {
    int columnCount = columnNames.length;
    return columnCount;
}
public int getRowCount() {
    int rowCount = data.size();
    return rowCount;
}
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return data.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
}
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
}
public String getColumnName(int column) {<br/>
return super.getColumnName(column);
}
```

}
.
.
.
This is how i create an object for the JTable

JTable table = new JTable(new CustomTableModel());

Comment: waht is the issue now.?

Comment: I posted answer, Let me know whether its solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit this code

```
public String getColumnName(int column) {
return columnNames[column];
}
```